# How to deal with variable with spaces in double quotes between single quotes

Tags: linux, bash

Here is what I have:

```
#!/bin/sh
var="file1 is installed\n\n"
var=$var"file2 is installed" 

...

su $USER -c 'export DISPLAY=0:0;zenity --info --text="<span size=\"large\">pylink library has been installed.</span>\n\nFiles are installed to: $* --title="eyelink_core lib" --ok-label="Ok"' "$var"

but when I run it, I always get: file1 is installed\n\nfile2 is installed: -c: line 0 unexpected EOF while looking for matching '"'
```

Anyone knows how to solve it? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`\n` is not treated specially in a double-quoted string. Use ANSI quoting instead.

```
var=$'file1 is installed\n\n'
```

Or, simply embed the newlines literally:

```
var="file1 is installed

"
```